# Change or rewrite add to cart button functionality "

Tags: actions

After clicking add to cart button by a user than i want to show checkout page in a popup instead of redirecting to cart, checkout pages.

My purpose is to show checkout page in a popup after clicking add to cart button

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Have you looked into this?  https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-on-popup-free/

Comment: Thank you it helps but it is not free....

Comment: It has a pro version and a free version - you can look over the way the free version functions and then use the same methods to build one yourself - that was my initial thinking.  You haven't provided much information so not sure what to recommend.